Bluetooth connecting issues on dual boot with Windows 10
I have Haylou X1 Pro Bluetooth earbuds. One day, I was using it normally on windows and switched to Ubuntu 22.04. After that, used it normally on Ubuntu, then got back to Windows, but for my surprise, it doesn't connect on Windows now. On Ubuntu, they connect and I can use it normally, but on Windows, it's impossible to connect. Not only the earbuds but my JBL GO 2 cannot connect on Windows.
I tried to uninstall the Bluetooth driver on Windows and update Ubuntu drivers, but nothing worked.
This is how it shows up on Windows:


See if this helps any https://github.com/x2es/bt-dualboot

This question is similar to: How to reconnect bluetooth headphones after dual boot to Windows 11?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
